# replace checkbox with unicode character

Tags: css

I am trying to replace the unchecked checkboxes with the following unicode character: ☐ or ◻

I tried doing this by making the checkboxes' content property the unicode character, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the CSS style that I tried to do the above with:

```
.question input[type='checkbox']{
    background:none;
    content:◻;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

How can I replace the checkbox or hide it and in its place have a unicode character?

Here is a JSFiddle where I am trying to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/mNsAv/

Comment: `content` can only be used with the `:before` or `:after` pseudos

Comment: oh, I didn't know that. I thought I had seen people use it in normal elements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Example with :before

http://jsfiddle.net/mNsAv/2/

```
.question input[type='checkbox'] + label:before {
    content:"◻";
}
.question input[type='checkbox']:checked + label:before {
    content:"✓";
}
.question input[type='checkbox'] {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: also some unicode goodness, proper chackboxes: ☐ ☑ ☒ http://jsfiddle.net/mNsAv/3/

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<label for="test">Label for my styled "checkbox"</label>
<label class="myCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test"/>
    <span></span>
</label>
```

CSS

```
.myCheckbox input {
    display: none;
}

.myCheckbox span:after {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
     content:"◻";
}

.myCheckbox input:checked + span:after {
    content:"B"; /*In here u have to use another unicode sign for checked */
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/kNVVm/)

[image]

Comment: I am trying to implement this in the full page, but it is not working. Here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/cheque/setup.html . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u change css ? i can't see it

Comment: Yes, I did. If you view the source, you can see I added the span, the class, and the :after (everything you did), but it is not showing here in my example.

Comment: <li class="question">
<input id="question4" type="checkbox" name="question">
<label for="question4">Question four asked here?</label>
</li>

Comment: .checkbox input {
    display: none;
}
.checkbox span:after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
.checkbox input:checked + span:after {
    content: "B";
}

Comment: u have added the css but u didn't added the html like the example above ?

Comment: I did. I just used a different class name. The label contains the input and the span.

Comment: see above image.i added a capture of your code.u didn't change the html like example i gave

Comment: the html that you circled is the html for the right two checkboxes. the left two where no checkboxes are shown are where I changed the html and need the checkboxes to be replaced with the unicode.

Comment: as i can see u edited left Question one asked here?
Question two asked here?  html.Not the left Question one asked here?
Question two asked here?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is very old. But I want to contribute with my code here:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/unicode-selectors-vezpvs?file=Selector%2Fstyles.scss

[image: selectorsUnicode]